# Simple pop up message in windows

Tags: java, dialog, popup, message, popupwindow

I'd like to do something similar to this for example: https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/140052.image0.jpg

Simply have my program display a message to windows, but it needs to be something that won't interfere with anything else windows does, for example, JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog will make windows focus on the message, which is not what I want.

For example, if I play a game, I don't to be aware of the message or have the message minimize my game etc.

Hope I explained it well enough, I tried searching for it but most of what I found was JOptionPane, JFrames and simiar, I don't even know if its possible, but I hope it is, thanks.

Comment: [Similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+dialog+without+focus+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: [How to Use the System Tray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer That was exactly what I needed!